# <link> and <div> in tables does not work anymore

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

I updated from TYPO3 6.2.14 to 6.2.17.

Up to now I used in tables DIVs and LINKs, e.g.

```
<div style="width:300px">chemistry</div>|Mr. X
<link 188>physics</link>|Mrs. Y
```

This doens't work anymore, I'm getting following output

```
<table class="contenttable contenttable-0">
    <tr class="tr-even tr-0">
        <td class="td-0">&lt;div style=&quot;width:300px&quot;&gt;chemistry&lt;/div&gt;</td>
        <td class="td-last td-1">Mr. X</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-odd tr-1">
        <td class="td-0">physics</td>
        <td class="td-last td-1">Mrs. Y</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

`<link>` isn't replaced any more, `<div>` are "wrapped"

How can I get the old behaviour?

Comment: Wait, did you have `<link 188>physics</link>` in your HTML source? Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I extended Pekka's answer to a "non-hacking" solution

The following typoscript below fixes this issue

```
tt_content.table{
    20.innerStdWrap.parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc
    20.innerStdWrap.htmlSpecialChars >
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> **Note:** The following is a hack. It undoes a change that was made for a (security) reason. I do not know the security implications. It would be preferable to find a way that doesn't require hacking the core.

I don't have a  Typo3 install running so I can't say for sure, but this *could* be the change that causes the new behaviour:

> [SECURITY] Replace parseFunc with htmlspecialchars in element "table"
>   /sysext/css_styled_content/static/v4.5/setup.txt
>   https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.CMS.git/commit/e737a34

```
-       20.innerStdWrap.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc
+       20.innerStdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
```

you may be able to change it back manually to `innerStdWrap.parseFunc = < lib.parseFunc`.